# Why Google Chrome does not delete session cookie when restart after crash?

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser, session-cookies

My web page set a session cookie when the user is connected.

If i kill the chrome process on windows, and then i restart the browser, my session cookie is here ! Why ?

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature, not a bug. Crashes usually are not intentional, and it would be a huge inconvenience to the user to have to log into everything all over again.

Crashing is not the same as exiting. If you want to restart the browser, quit it the normal way, not by killing it.

Comment: Ok thanks. How can i do to be able to detect this case ? I would like to delete my cookie when chrome restart due to a crash?

Comment: What's so hard about exiting your browser normally, that you have to force it to exit?